# OSX Mavericks Apache Added Virtualhost Loads Localhost instead

Tags: wordpress, macos, apache

Been working on a locahost VHost setup for a WordPress Roots development environment with Bedrock including Composer, Capistrano and WP CLI using Homebrew on my OSX Mavericks Mac Mini all morning. I am using Homebrew's PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.6.19 and OSX's Apache. Thought I had sort of understood Apache VirtualHost inner workings, but I am missing something.

I added img.local to `/etc/hosts`

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost img.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost img.local 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost img.local
```

and have this in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jasper@img.local             
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jasperfrumau/webdesign/img/web"
    ServerName img.local             
    ServerAlias www.img.local             
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/img.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/img.local-access_log" common

   <Directory "/Users/jasperfrumau/webdesign/img/web/">
        Option FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted the server using `apachectl -k restart` as root after I checked the config using `apachectl -S` . It said I was all good:

```
apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

When I load img.local in my browser the root localhost is loaded. So either my img.local is still bypassed because of a faulty vhosts file or there is something else in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I need to change. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: When I run `http://localhost:80/server-status` I get a 404. Not sure if that is normal for an OSX Mavericks Apache setup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I realised the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` was loading the vhosts from `/private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf` so I added one img.conf there and restarted the server. There were some errors in the file after all once it was read. This is the correct one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jasper@img.local             
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jasperfrumau/webdesign/img/web"
    ServerName img.local             
    ServerAlias www.img.local             
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/img.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/img.local-access_log" common

   <Directory "/Users/jasperfrumau/webdesign/img/web/">
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```